# 5V and +5v charger adapter, What is the difference?

Tags: power, charger, adapter

I am trying to buy a stand-alone charger for my Archos 48 500Gb Internet media player. I think it uses a charger which is `Output 5V 2A`, but I recently came across [a charger](http://www.expansys.com/aiptek-power-adapter+5v-2a-usb-type-mini-b-5-pin-uk-223933/) that says `Output +5V 2A`.

Is this the same as `Output 5V 2A` and would it work with the Archos without damage? What is the meaning of that '+'?

Comment: Our site is for discussions related to the design of electronics and, I regret to inform you, not for consumer electronics support.

Answer (score 2):

The + symbol refers to the output being positive.  In practice, unless there as a - symbol in front of the voltage, you are almost always dealing with a positive voltage.

In this case, that charger will work fine with your device so long as it has the right connector for it.

Comment: Thanks Toby and Tony. Pls if it is regulated as you say how would that affect my player? and if not regulated how would it also affect it?

Answer (score 1):

Some DC bricks were not regulated so the Vdc was only at rated current and unloaded could be 6 or moreV  This one may be regulated. The + implies it is DC not AC. thats all.  Its redundant unless you wanted a jack changer with +/-
It should work but not knowing if it is regulated or not is a concern..  Ask them..

Comment: Pls is it is regulated how would it affect my player?

Comment: if it is not regulated there may be substantial AC hum. I cannot say for sure how excess voltage can affect your player. It may work,